# OpenJPA not returning all entity values?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, persistence, openjpa

I changed the datatype of 'groupChat' from boolean to int and since then the attribute 'groupChat' is not returned when my rest service retrieves ConversationEntity's. I am using OpenJPA with a MySQL database. The column 'group_chat' in the MySQL database is of TINYINT(4) datatype.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="conversations")
@JsonDeserialize
public class ConversationEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "conversation_id")
private int conversationID;

@Column(name = "started_at")
private Timestamp startedAt;
    
@Column(name = "group_chat")
private int groupChat;

@Column(name="group_chat_id")
private int groupChatID;
```

Here is the output when my rest service is called

```
[
{
    "conversationID": 2,
    "startedAt": 1585671702615,
    "groupChatID": 0
},
{
    "conversationID": 10,
    "startedAt": 1595848147884,
    "groupChatID": 0
},
{
    "conversationID": 22,
    "startedAt": 1597676709513,
    "groupChatID": 0
},
{
    "conversationID": 6,
    "startedAt": 1586022468182,
    "groupChatID": 0
}
]
```

As you can see, no 'groupChat'. The same actually happens if I try to add an attribute to existing entity (having already created the corresponding column in MySQL). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is this your actual response? `timestamp` is defined as `startedAt` so asked. also, use `Integer` instead of `int`

Comment: Sorry my mistake, yes that is my actual response. Using Integer did not help.